# User click working, Jquery click not working

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I am creating a script that automatically clicks the "accept request" button on a social media site.
To execute it I use tampermonkey.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    addFriend();

});

function addFriend(){

    $(".acceptRequest").each(function(){

        var button = this;

            setTimeout(function(){
                button.click();
            },1);

    });

}
```

When this runs I get the

> Uncaught ReferenceError:

however when clicking the button myself it obviously is working.

So what is the diffrence between clicking it myself and letting jquery click it?

EDIT:
The exact error is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: manageRequest is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (requests:2107)
    at Object.trigger (userscript.html?id=2ad30bde-066c-4303-83a2-eae54846284e:5)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (userscript.html?id=2ad30bde-066c-4303-83a2-eae54846284e:5)
    at Function.each (userscript.html?id=2ad30bde-066c-4303-83a2-eae54846284e:5)
    at w.fn.init.each (userscript.html?id=2ad30bde-066c-4303-83a2-eae54846284e:5)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (userscript.html?id=2ad30bde-066c-4303-83a2-eae54846284e:5)
    at eval (userscript.html?id=2ad30bde-066c-4303-83a2-eae54846284e:45)
```

And this is the button I'm trying to click:

```
<button type="button" class="acceptRequest" onclick="manageRequest(bunch of userinformation here)"><span>accept</span></button>
```

Comment: What exactly is the ReferenceError?

Comment: Try `$(button).click()`.

Comment: What type of element is `.acceptRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `click`, instead use `trigger`, which execute handlers attached to the matched element for a given event type. So, your code would look like the one below.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(button).trigger( "click" );
},1);
```

You can learn more about jQuery's `trigger()` in [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).